# FK in mysql, changing the parent id value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this trouble.

My zone table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zone` (
`id_zone` INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_zone`),
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Hotel table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hotel` (
`id_hotel` INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`hotel_zone_id` INT unsigned ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_hotel`),
INDEX (`hotel_zone_id`)
FOREIGN KEY (hotel_zone_id) REFERENCES zone(`id_zone`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Here is an example of my ddbb.

```
Zone
id_zone
1
2
3
4
5
```

Hotel Table

```
id_hotel hotel_zone_id
   1           1
   2           1 
   3           2
   4           2
   5           3
```

So I want to set all the hotels with zone id 1 to 10.

My query is:

```
UPDATE zone SET id_zone=10 WHERE id_zone=1;
```

and I get this error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: I want to change the parent table ID(zone.id_zone) from 1 to 10 and then it has to be changed in the hotel table... or no?

Comment: Hm... your example seems to work, no? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed438/1

Comment: Correctly the problem was with another fields!

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared your FK as `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, this should work. The referenced records should automatically be updated.

However, from your description, I gather that what you want to do is actually this:

```
UPDATE Hotel SET hotel_zone_id=10 WHERE hotel_zone_id=1;
```